# Negative integer comparison on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, integer

I'm running into a frustrating problem and can't figure out the reason.
I'm working on an Arudino (UNO) with C++ and try to find if an integer is negative or positive, just that. But:

```
const int32_t remaining = (int32_t)item->delay.delay - chrono;
serialPrintlnf("remaining=%d", remaining);
serialPrintlnf("remaining>0=%d", remaining > 0);
serialPrintlnf("remaining<0=%d", remaining < 0);
serialPrintlnf("max(remaining, 0)=%d", max(remaining, 0));
```

(chrono is an `int32_t` member of the class), results in:

```
remaining=-1565
remaining>0=1
remaining<0=0
max(remaining, 0)=-1565
```

In noticed that max is actually implemented in Arduino.h#93 as

```
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

So it is not surprising that it fails too.
I noticed that hardcoding remaining to -1 will work, but I expect it is the compiler that kicks in and remove the comparisons altogether.

Something weird appears when trying `Serial.println(remaining, BIN);`, it gives `100111111100011001111` for `-1841`, which doesn't correspond to the 16bits nor the 32bits 2-complements representation.

The results are the same when remaining is actually positive. IDE claims that the comparaison used is `operator <(long, long)`, which seems correct (Visual Studio 2017, although it may be confused by the fact that the code is compiled for the Arduino, not my processor). I tried to change 0 to 0L, casting it to `int32_t`, replacing it by -1, invoking Beelzebub, to no avail.

What (obvious?) thing am I missing here ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `int` is less than 32 bits, and therefore `%d` isn't the correct format to display `int32_t`.

Comment: What is »not surprising that it fails« about the `max` macro? It looks fine to me.

Comment: If the < fails, it is not surprising that `max` fails too, since it uses the same operator, the last test case is not really different from the previous one

Comment: To clarify my comment above, I believe that `<` works fine. It's the printf that fails and shows that a positive number is negative.

Comment: To confirm @interjay's guess, `int` on Arduino is 16 bit. Use `%ld` and cast to `long`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the expression `(int32_t)item->delay.delay - chrono` is unsigned due to arithmetic conversions (I'm guessing that chrono is a `uint32_t`, which has the same rank as `int32_t`), making the compiler assume the result can't be lesser than zero. Casting both sides would probably resolve this.

Comment: Wouldn't the `remaining > 0` work at least in that case? I started checking all that because I make that comparaison in a if statement that was always entered, even when remaining was negative.

Comment: @Hasturkun chrono is int32_t, and I tried `((int32_t)item->delay.delay) - chrono` to be sure

Comment: @LuxOrïk: That doesn't really change anything. Try `(int32_t)item->delay.delay - (int32_t)chrono`?

Comment: Using `%ld` and casting to`long` does indeed show some weird results such as 1308180 for -2411, but how should I fix that ? Why is it behaving as unsigned arithmetics when everything is forced into signed ?

Comment: std::cout knows the right type by design!

Comment: @Hasturkun Tried it, doesn't work :( (and chrono is already int32_t)

Comment: @LuxOrïk 1307667 is a perfectly valid signed number that happens to be positive.

Comment: @interjay But 1308180 is not the result of 256-2667, and I'm not finding where I'm screwing up the operation

Comment: @LuxOrïk There's nothing shown here that indicates the numbers are really 256 and 2667. In all likelihood you printed them wrong as well.

Comment: @interjay You're getting near! Those value were perfectly expected, so I didn't checked them but the 256 printed with `%ld` and as a `long` gives 1310976. This value come from a `uint32_t` field. So you're right my usage of `serialPrintlnf` is completely wrong. So the problem is completely elsewhere, what should I do of this question ?